# using mongodb c++ drivers in a Qt application written with qtcreator

Tags: c++, linux, mongodb, qt

I've compiled and installed the C++ driver for MongoDB using [this](http://mongoc.org/libmongoc/current/installing.html) guide. now I have no Idea how my `.pro` file should be in order to use it in my Qt project which I'm using qtcreator to build. I'm using a build machine with Debian Linux as OS. The MongoDB driver is installed in `/usr/local/`. I'm trying to compile [this](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-cxx-driver/mongocxx-v3/tutorial/) tutorial.

Comment: You followed the instructions to install the `C` driver, but not those for the `C++` driver. The `C` driver is a prerequisite to building the `C++` driver, but you need to build both if you want to follow the tutorial you linked to.